# I can't listen express server on port 80

Tags: node.js, express, server, port

I'm trying to create an express server using node.js but when I start the server on port 80 my friends can't use it. I can select any other port and it will work, but when I try port 80 it doesn't work. I'm using https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and https://portchecker.co/check to check if the port is openned, I tried with 3000 and it work perfectly, but I need to get it working in port 80. I have already disabled my firewall and setup my DMZ host in the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using windows as OS. In it the port 80 could be used as default port for some service. Please check the following -

- Skype uses port 80 by default, you can change this in skype options > advanced > connection - and uncheck "use port 80"
- Port 80 is the standard HTTP port, so to check which services are using you could run `net stop http`. It will list the services using port 80 and will ask to whether end them or not.
- Port 80 could be occupied by IIS server. Please stop IIS and then re-run the node service.
- Some SQL Server Reporting services also use port 80